# BQML model exported to Vertex model registry fails to deploy to endpoint

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

I re-ran a BQML SQL statement for a model that is has been deployed to an online prediction endpoint for the last 6 months;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE MODEL
  dataset.bq_model OPTIONS (model_type='matrix_factorization',
    .
    .
    .
    model_registry="vertex_ai",
    vertex_ai_model_id='bqml_vertex_model_name'
```

the BQ statement runs to completion and I can see the version increment in Vertex model registry and that the model is imported to Vertex, however when I try to deploy it (yesterday and today) both by gcloud cli command and by the web console to a Vertex Endpoint it fails with;

```
Failed to export BQML model: 
project_id: "project_id"
dataset_id: "dataset"
model_id: "bq_model"
```

Anyone seen this before? what does that mean, it seems inconsistent that the model is exported, but can't be exported, what other things should I check, I can't see any errors in the logs in Vertex.

Comment: You might be able to find more information about the error message by exploring logs in the [google cloud logs explore](https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/query?_ga=2.197732143.1283289355.1687144867-2074507857.1686323886\&_gac=1.89587177.1687154301.Cj0KCQjw1rqkBhCTARIsAAHz7K2QrEg1vMIJgEXmIwtB8_YoLNQGoUyRoEiLkUTiGdGPtQAf_5ffKxkaApXJEALw_wcB). For more information you can refer to this [link](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs-explorer-interface).